# How to calculate Running Total in SQL Server 2012

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2012, cumulative-sum

It is an actuarial report. 
The logic is to calculate the number of Policies that have Loss (have loss date on it).

This is `EffectiveMMYY` and Count of `PolicyNumbers`. This is the number of policies that we sold each month. Im showing only the ones that have claims on it.

[image]

We do not count Policies that do not have any loss on it.

And this is Count of PolicyNumbers by LossMMYY (month,when the loss was reported)

[image]

I have matrix with

**Rows**: `EffectiveMMYY`,

**Columns**: `LossMMYY`,

**Value**: `SUM(PolicyNumberCount)`

[image]

How to calculate in SQL running total for `EffectiveMMYY` so the result would look like this:

[image]

Sample data:

```
DECLARE @Table1 TABLE 
                (
                     ID INT, 
                     PolicyNumber VARCHAR(50),
                     EffectiveDate DATE,
                     LossDate DATE
                )

INSERT INTO @Table1 (ID, PolicyNumber, EffectiveDate, LossDate)
VALUES (1, 'Pol1', '2017-02-01',  '2017-02-05'),    
       (2, 'Pol2', '2017-03-04',   '2017-03-18'),   
       (3, 'Pol3', '2017-03-11', '2017-03-22'),
       (4, 'Pol4', '2017-03-11',  NULL),    
       (5, 'Pol5', '2017-03-15', '2017-04-22'),
       (6, 'Pol6', '2017-04-18', '2017-04-19'), 
       (7, 'Pol7', '2017-04-22', '2017-04-29'),
       (8, 'Pol8', '2017-04-15', '2017-04-18'), 
       (9, 'Pol9', '2017-12-15', '2018-01-23'),
       (10, 'Pol10', '2017-02-13', '2017-03-11'),
       (11, 'Pol11', '2017-02-18', '2017-03-22'),
       (12, 'Pol12', '2017-02-17', '2018-01-05'),
       (13, 'Pol13', '2017-05-28', '2017-05-30')

SELECT 
    ID, PolicyNumber,
    FORMAT(EffectiveDate, 'MMM') + '-'+ FORMAT(EffectiveDate, 'yy') AS  'EffectiveMMYY',
    FORMAT(LossDate, 'MMM') + '-'+ FORMAT(LossDate, 'yy') AS  'LossMMYY',
    1 AS PolicyNumberCount
FROM
    @Table1 
ORDER BY 
    EffectiveDate
```

**Result of above query looks like this:**

[image]

I tried this:

```
count(PolicyNumber) OVER (partition BY MONTH(EffectiveDate), YEAR(EffectiveDate) order by EffectiveDate ) as runtotEffMonth,
```

But it didn't give me correct result

Comment: Can you explain the output? It makes no sense to me at all. You have dates in each row and dates as columns but no idea what the logic is here.

Comment: Basically it is actuarial loss report. I need to calculate the number of Policies that have loss on it. ( so it should have a loss date)

Comment: But you need to explain the logic. What are the values in the rows and columns? They both have dates but no idea what is what. And no idea how you come up with the numbers you are getting. I don't mean the sql, I mean an explanation of the business rules.

Comment: So from all policies that we sold in Effective Month, lets say Feb-17 - only one was reported Loss (Claim) on Feb-17 (Column). I also updated question

Comment: Ahh look up dynamic pivot. This has been asked and answered hundreds and hundreds of times.

Comment: Thanks. I will look into that

Answer (score 0):

```
with POL as (
select 
    FORMAT(EffectiveDate, 'yyyy-MM') aS  EffYYYYMM,
    FORMAT(LossDate, 'yyyy-MM') aS  LossYYYYMM
from @Table1
where lossdate is not null
)
select
    PE.EffYYYYMM,
    PL.LossYYYYMM,
    coalesce((
        select count(*)
        from pol p2
        where p2.EffYYYYMM = pE.EffYYYYMM
        and p2.LossYYYYMM <= pL.LossYYYYMM
    ), 0) as PolCount
from POL PE
cross join pol PL
group by 
    PE.EffYYYYMM,
    PL.LossYYYYMM 
order by 1,2
```